# Class 'Form' not found in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5.2 form class in app.php is:

```
'aliases' => [
 // ...
  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
 // ...
],
```

But this code not work in Laravel 5.3.

How to add class `Form` in Laravel 5.3 ?

Comment: It works for me. What is the exact error message?

Comment: If it's a new project, make sure you're pulling in the form-helper package with `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"`.

Comment: @Quasdunk Oh tanks, i forget this packages

Comment: @Avram Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its called the Laravel Collective package and It has been removed from laravel defaults.

You can still integrate and use it.

here is the documentation
[Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

**How to Install**

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

1st step install this via composer

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

[Laravel Collective here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#generating-urls)

2nd step add this line in config/app.php under providers

```
    'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

3rd step

add this 2 line in config/app.php under aliases array

```
    'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

final step then link your html and css this way

```
{{ Html::style('css/demo.css') }}
{{ Html::script('js/demo.js') }}
```